# Stuck with foreign-architecture=i386 when using apt-get

Tags: 11.10, apt

I installed some packages a while ago and for some reason, they would only install with a special set of parameters that I used as recommended on a website (can't remember which one).

Now, although harmless, I am stuck with these warnings every time I run apt-get:

```
dpkg: warning: ignoring option --foreign-architecture=i386: this architecture cannot be foreign
```

Any idea where is this lying around? How can I clean this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm. Removing the line 
foreign-architecture i386

in the file `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch`

Removes the warning message:
Unknown configuration key `foreign-architecture' found in your`dpkg'
configuration files.  This warning will become a hard error at a later
date, so please remove the offending configuration options and replace
them with `dpkg --add-architecture' invocations at the command line.

when performing the command: `sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 4):

It's part of the new multiarch system that lets you install foreign-arch packages on your system.

Have a look at the file(s) in `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/`, you should see it in there.

I think it's safe to remove if you don't want to use multiarch though I don't know why it should be warning in the first place. Is your physical arch i386 as well or something?

Answer (score 1):

just go to the required destination and delete the 'foreign-architecture i386' line.It works.