# Change the url for fetching updated packages in Ubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, updates

I have a problem about updating the rabbitmq package in **Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS**. It gives errors when I run `sudo apt update`:

```
E: Failed to fetch https://ppa1.novemberain.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-erlang/deb/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 104.21.27.7 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://ppa1.novemberain.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/deb/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 104.21.27.7 443]
```

Then I found the reason for such errors is that "the mirror does not have i386 (32-bit) packages. We never produced them or published for 32-bit. Maybe Cloudsmith itself indexes arch-neutral packages for i386 but Erlang Debian packages are not arch-neutral (while RabbitMQ Debian packages are)" (https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/discussions/8934)

I am using a 64-bit machine and I do not know why the `sudo apt update` tries to fetch the package via a non-existing url for 32-bit machines. How should I change the url to a correct one?

I looked into both `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `etc/apt/sources.list.d/rabbitmq.list`, and I did not find the same url for 32-bit machines appeared in the error messages above. I only found these urls in the list, which look very close to them:

```
./sources.list.d/rabbitmq.list.save:deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/rabbitmq.E495BB49CC4BBE5B.gpg] https://ppa1.novemberain.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-erlang/deb/ubuntu focal main
./sources.list.d/rabbitmq.list.save:deb-src [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/rabbitmq.E495BB49CC4BBE5B.gpg] https://ppa1.novemberain.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-erlang/deb/ubuntu focal main
./sources.list.d/rabbitmq.list:deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/rabbitmq.E495BB49CC4BBE5B.gpg] https://ppa1.novemberain.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-erlang/deb/ubuntu focal main
./sources.list.d/rabbitmq.list:deb-src [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/rabbitmq.E495BB49CC4BBE5B.gpg] https://ppa1.novemberain.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-erlang/deb/ubuntu focal main
```

Comment: You probably ran `dpkg --add-architecture i386` for some reason, which is why apt started asking repos for `i386` package lists as well. Assuming that is actually needed, just add `arch=amd64` next to the `signed-by` option for the affected repo.

Comment: If the `i386` arch isn't needed, use https://askubuntu.com/a/988858/158442 to remove it

Comment: @muru Thanks it worked!